# MVC passing parameters with url devided by /

Tags: url, parameter-passing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question regarding passing the parameters to controller with url.

Bascially imagine I have to pass 2 values, namely id and token, so if i do the folling url

```
website.com/controller/{id}
```

Then to my controller I get id, but i'm wondering is it possible to do something like that:
`website.com/controller/{id}/{token}` so that both of them are passed as parameters? Because now it doesn't work.

Or maybe not through slash but on some other way NOT like `webiste/contoller?id={id}&token={token}`

Maybe something like this: `website/contoller/{id}&{token}`

I would like to have it more subtile avoiding the parameter namings ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following route pattern:

```
{controller}/{action}/{id}/{token}
```

All you have to do is modify your routing configuration. But bear in mind that this automatically makes the `{id}` token compulsory because only the last parameter of a route can be optional:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{token}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Now your controller actions could have both parameters:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string token)
{
    ...
}
```